# Printing the index of an iterator in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I am using the `find()` method of `std::map`, which returns an *iterator*.
However I need the **index** of the found element; for example: 0, which corresponds to `std::map::begin()`, and so on.

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::map< int, int > aMap;
  aMap.insert( std::make_pair(100, 50) );
  aMap.insert( std::make_pair(200, 40) );
  aMap.insert( std::make_pair(300, 60) );

  std::map< int, int >::iterator it_map = aMap.find(300);
  if (it_map != aMap.end())
    std::cout << it_map << "\n"; // error

}
```

That doesn't compile and I know the reason. However, I need a way to print `2` because the index of 300 is 2.

For that simple example, you may say that map (binary tree) is not a good container. However, in the real code, there are tons of elements that I have to search and binary tree is good for that.

Any idea?

Comment: How you define the index of a binary tree structure?

Comment: @40two: A map isn't necessarily a implemented as a tree, and doesn't have a tree-like interface; but it is ordered, so you can define an index according to that order as the question describes.

Comment: @MikeSeymour As per standard it isn't necessarily implemented as a tree, agreed. However, in every implementation I know is implemented as a tree. Moreover, when an insertion or extraction occurs, any previous order is disturbed. Consequently, as your answer correctly states you can define an index but only for the `std::map`'s currend state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need the index, then perhaps a map is the wrong data type; you need to iterate through the map (in linear time) to find the index, losing the benefit of the logarithmic-time search.

Perhaps a sorted vector, using the `lower_bound` algorithm to find elements in logarithmic time, might be more suitable. Then you can subtract the resulting random-access iterator from the `begin()` iterator in constant time.

Nevertheless, if you do want to use a map:

```
std::cout << std::distance(aMap.begin(), it_map) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::distance`, like this :

```
std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(aMap),it_map) << endl;
```

Documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/)